# Convert SAP BI hierarchy to flat table

Tags: excel, powerquery, hierarchy, sap-bw

I have the below "old" table where Level "1" is top level, "CC" is the smallest unit inside our company:

[image: Old table]

What I want to do is convert this table into a flat table with additional column like level 1 / level 2 / Level 3, which show parent department of each node,

e.g. `100111 |CC |3 |IS// |IS/ |IS`.

[image: New Table]

Using Excel I can do it easily by using some conditional formula and copy the cell above if current cell is `CC`.

My process is like this: SAP Application (export) -> .xls file (without Level and Parent Columns) -> creating new column for level and parent node with power query -> make new column (level 1 - 6) like example in the new table.

For Column Level "1", I use this formula:

```
If(B2=1;A2;D1)
```

and I fill it down for the rest. In my data, the first row is always level 1.

For Level 2:

```
=IF(B2=2(//because is Level 2),A2,IF(B2<2,"",E1))
```

And I repeat the same formula for other Column.

Can someone suggest me a solution for this problem?

Comment: What are you running your powerquery against? SAP? What's the table and fields that contains this data? What's the database platform?

Comment: thank for coming back to me. My process is like this: SAP Application (export)-> xls file (without Level and Parent Columns) -> creating new column for level and parent node with power query -> make new column (level 1 - 6) like example in the new table. Currently i'm stucking at last step.

Comment: Can you explain the "Parent" logic e.g. what does it mean when the 505599 has a "Parent" value of 5?

Comment: Hi. When the 505599 has a "Parent" value of 5, it means that the last node which connects to 505599, has Level 5. My table is extracted from a SAP Analysis Office table, which comes with drill down and hierachy function. The Analysis office table is itself a Pivot Table, but it has a limitation with data size (< 200.000 lines). If we have more than 200.000 lines in our table, our excel crashs. So we decided to use  Power Query and Power Pivot as a supporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Power Query equivalent of your first formula would be to Add a Column with this formula:

`if [Level] = 1 then [Department] else null`

I would follow that with a "Fill / Down" step (from the Transform ribbon).

The subsequent formulas would look similar, e.g. for Level 2

`if [Level] = 2 then [Department] else null`

Follow each with a "Fill / Down" step and you should be done.

Comment: Yes, i received the same answer in other forum. But it worked perfectly til level 3. Since level 4 i got a new problem. Some cost center have only 3 parent nodes ( e.g. IS | IS/ | IS/S) but it was filled the value of previous Cost Center with more level (e.g IS | IS/| IS/12 | IS/123). I had a workaround with duplicate column for each level and remove the old one. Could you suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: It sounds like the order of the rows is crucial? If so, you probably need to determine the "Parent Department" code for each row. I'd add an Index column and then use something like: `if [Level] = "CC" then null else #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Department]` , followed by a Fill / Down.